# How to detect touch over a UIView when touched over a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, events, uiview, uibutton, touch

I'm using `(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, and `(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to handle some dragging on a `UIView`.  This `UIView` however have some UIButtons as subviews of the `UIView` and when the user touches over a `UIButton` (which are also over the `UIView`) the touches methods aren't called.

I need the touch methods in the `UIView` to be called at all times and still have the UIButtons working, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try to accept your previous answers......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, no problem, I solved my question already.

The way is to override the touch methods in the buttons also like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    touchMoved = NO;
    [[self superview] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    touchMoved = YES;
    [[self superview] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!touchMoved) [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The `touchMoved` variable is meant to track if it was a direct touch to the button or if the touch was meant to drag the superview.  As I'm using `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` then it works fine if I disable the touchesEnded when it has tracked a touch movement.